# Setting up Wordpress site on WAMPSERVER

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to setup a wordpress site (which is already running on production) on my local PC. I installed and setup wampserver 2.5 , installed wordpress under the root directory as "C:/Program Files/wamp/wamp/www/wordpress" . When I open the URL localhost:88/wordpress , it opens the helloworld wordpress welcome page . Then I went onto install my wordpress site by copying the site folder under the same directory as "C:/Program Files/wamp/wamp/www/**talent-awards**", but this time when I open the URL localhost:88/talent-awards in the browser , it says page not found . I am new to wordpress and WAMP , so not sure what I have missed out .

Help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks in advance .
Jos

Comment: Can you see the folder if you go to just http://localhost:88?

Comment: Yes the folder is listed under "Your Projects" , is there anything inside the talent-awards that I need to check ?

Comment: You should enable error reporting so you can see what is going on. Take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying site folder(from server) to localhost. Am I right? If so, in the website database, you can find wp_options table. There you need to change the site url and home address to your localhost address[in your case  localhost:88].

It is better to do Searchandreplace on your db.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Thanks for your advice , I have migrated the db , made changes to wp_options for the home and siteurl parameters , set up the error logging as suggested on the link . However , now the error has changed and is showing 404 Not found. Seems I am still missing something !

Comment: Are you able to login to wordpress admin. Check the general settings and Reading section. Did you have same table prefix(wp_ or something like this) in both database table and wp-config.php file? If not , please change and check. After that, flushing your mod_rewrite rules by changing permalinks: Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks->Save settings

Comment: I noticed some strange behavior . Like I said , although I changed the siteurl and home URLs in the wp_options table in the db , the moment I try to open the page http://localhost:88/talent-awards/wp-admin , it changes my the values of these fields in the db back to http://example.com and also the browser gets redirected to example.com page . Also can you please explain what you mean by  " Did you have same table prefix(wp_ or something like this) in both database table and wp-config.php file? "

Comment: I meant, you can find $table_prefix  = 'wp_'; something like this in your wp-config.php file. In your database, you can find tables like wp_option, wp_postmeta etc. Please make sure that the table prefix('wp_') and $table_prefix in wp-config.php file are same. If it is not working for you, give me your email address in email-id[at]domain.com format. I will send you a search and replace file for db. It will help you a lot.

Comment: thanks, the wp.config has $table_prefix  = 'wp_'; and all the tables are starting with wp_ , what else do you suggest that I should check . Also you could send the file to the emailid : forinfo.js[at]gmail.com

Comment: Thanks , I copied the file you sent in the site folder and http://localhost:88/talent-awards/searchreplacedb2.php . However the results remain the same , still 404 not found when I hit , http://localhost:88/talentawards.com

Comment: Your website folder is talent-awards or talentawards.com. what did you put in wp-options table for site url and home. If your website folder is talent-awards then the site url value should be localhost:88/talent-awards. Check properly and try.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to do:

1. Backup your existing production backup and restore it on your local database instance
2. Update the database information in the wp-config.php to match your local database instance

   ```
   /** The name of the database for WordPress */
   define('DB_NAME', '');

   /** MySQL database username */
   define('DB_USER', '');

   /** MySQL database password */
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

   /** MySQL hostname - You probably only need to change this one */
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   ```
3. Use a database migration tool, like this one https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB . This will update the restored database to match your localhost configuration.

If you already have a database ready to be used by the website you can skip step 1 and 3.